# Remove default style of input type="file"

Tags: html, css

I am trying to upload a document onclick of icon.But I am unable to remove the default style of `input type="file"`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <label class="btn-btn-default">
    <i class="fa fa-upload fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>Upload Document
    <input type="file" class="form-control col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
  </label>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/qze50cyg/)**

Please any suggestion

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/uer3ow/total-input-type-file-style-control-with-pure-css Please refer this link.

Comment: @SreenathPG Sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2:** 
Try this :)

```js
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            $(".fa-upload").css("color", "green");
        }else{
          $(".fa-upload").css("color", "black");
        }
    }
 
 
 $("#inputFile").change(function () {
        readURL(this);
    });
```

```css
.file-upload {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <label class="btn-btn-default">
    <div class="fa fa-upload fa-2x ">Upload Image</div>
    <input id="inputFile" class="file-upload" type="file" accept="image/*" />
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to chenge the color of  `label` after uploading document.How to do it?

Comment: Check now! When you select file then it will turn green and if not-selected then it turns black :)

Answer (score 1):

Add one class to the input field. Then in CSS hide it.

```
<input type="file" class="hideMe form-control col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                        
<style>
.hideMe{
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

do the following:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <label class="btn-btn-default">
                            <i id="1" onclick="do2()" class="fa fa-upload fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>Upload Document
                            <input id="2" style="display:none;"type="file" class="form-control col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 ">
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

And add this to your javascript to simulate the input behavior on your icon:

```
Function do2(){
 document.getElementById("2").click;
}
```

Comment: it should be  document.getElementById("2").click();

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type=file]::file-selector-button{
  visibility: hidden;
  color: transparent;
}

input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button{
  visibility: hidden;
  color: transparent;
}
```